# No response when calling read() method of oData model

Tags: odata, sapui5

I have a problem that no data returns when I read an OData service via ODataModel.

[image]

But when I copy the request URL directly to web browser I can get through the odata service and the results are listed. Can you please help on this issue?

Comment: You code seems syntactically correct. What UI5 version are you running this on and also what is the URL created in the network requests ?

Comment: Thank you Stephen! My UI5 version is 1.46.10. The url created in the application is like: https://webidetesting1323832-w5c8af98c.dispatcher.int.sap.hana.ondemand.com/sap/opu/odata/xxx/XC_ACCOVR_SRV/AccountSet?$filter=CustomerExternalID%20eq%20%27S101214%27

I can call this url in the web browser and it works well. But the response is empty when calling this service in my application.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved because of some CORS coding in the backend services.